# Running Macro when cell changes in specific range vba

Tags: vba, excel

I created this yesterday and it was working fine but today it is no longer working. The goal is to have a drop down menu that allows for `Y` and `N`. If the operator picks `Y` (we'll say in cell Y11), then because the cells beneath it contain the formula `=IF($Y$11="Y","Y","")` then it will turn to `Y` and every cell beneath it will do the same (Chain reaction).

If the operator decides they were wrong to put `Y` there, then they can go back, click `N`, and it will replace that cell with the original formula.

As I said, this was working yesterday but now is not. Does anyone see any weak points in the code? This is being pasted into the sheet rather than a module.

```
Private Sub Reverse_NewBatch_Mistake(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("Y12:Y36")) Is Nothing Then
        If ActiveCell = "Y" Then
            'do nothing
        End If

        If ActiveCell = "N" Then
            variable = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Address
            ActiveCell.Formula = "=if(" & variable & "=""Y"",""Y"","""")"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you debug the code? E.g. put a breakpoint at the first line, do you even hit that breakpoint?

Comment: Since this is created in a sheet, it is not allowing me to debug. I am not used to macros outside of modules so maybe I am doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your desired result by using the Worksheet_Change event as below.

Simply place the code below under the worksheet you want to work with, the code also removes the need for all the cells to have formulas in them:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("Y12:Y36")
'declare and set the range you wish to react as a chain reaction
    If Target.Address = "$Y$11" Then 'if cell Y11 has changed value
        If Target.Value = "Y" Then 'if the value is "Y" then
            rng = "Y" 'set the whole range as "Y"
        Else
            rng = "" 'else empty the range
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

Following from the comments, the code below will auto fill the range below the cell where the "Y" was entered until the last row on the rng:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
'disable events so the work we do below doesn't set the Change event again
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("Y12:Y36")
    'declare and set the range you wish to react as a chain reaction
    Dim i As Long
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        For i = (Target.Row + 1) To (rng.Rows.Count + rng.Row - 1)
        'loop through from where the value was entered to the last row specified in rng
            If Target.Value = "Y" Then 'if value is "Y" then
                ws.Cells(i, "Y").Value = "Y" 'enter "Y" in the range below
            Else
                ws.Cells(i, "Y").Value = "" 'else empty cells below
            End If
        Next i
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: My understanding of the OP's question is that the "Y11" was only an example cell, and that they'd like the same result (auto fill cells **below**) for any cell who's value changes......

Comment: Hi Xabier, thanks for the answer. I need this to only produce Y in each cell below the 1st cell in the Y range that is manually changes to Y using a data validation List. So if I said Y to cell Y16 instead, it would only populate Y in the cells beneath that.

Comment: Ahhh misunderstood the question, will have another check when I have some time. Sorry folks.

Comment: @Jordan updated my answer, I believe it should now work as you expect it to. Do let me know if you come across any issues. :)